# Error creating ElasticSearch domain using Terraform - Exactly one subnet needed

Tags: elasticsearch, terraform

I may have come across some conflicting docs today.

When creating an Elastic Search domain with vpc options, the HashiCorp Terraform official docs (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticsearch_domain.html)  say that the subnets is a list and even specify 2 subnets in their example. However when I specify 2 subnets I get an error (I tried 2 different ways of specifying the subnets list) -

```
  vpc_options {
      subnet_ids = "${var.private_subnet_ids}" 
       OR 
      subnet_ids = [
         "${var.private_subnet_ids[0]}",
         "${var.private_subnet_ids[1]}"
      ]
```

Both of them give me the same error -

```
Error: Error creating ElasticSearch domain: ValidationException: You must specify exactly one subnet.
    status code: 400, request id: 98b49b34-2da8-11ea-8114-e9488cc7cb63

  on modules/es/main.tf line 51, in resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es":
  51: resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es" {
```

If I specify a single subnet, it works fine.

```
subnet_ids = ["${var.private_subnet_ids[0]}"]
```

I do however want to be able to specify both of my private subnets for the ES cluster. 
Is there a way to do that ? I noticed a couple issues on github for this but the resolution was what was in the Terraform docs and that does not work for me. I am using `v0.12.17` in case it matters.

variable `private_subnet_ids` is a list

```
variable "private_subnet_ids" {
  type        = "list"
  description = "The list of private subnets to place the instances in"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html) explains the structure behind the Terraform behavior. Each ES Domain can only connect to one subnet if it resides in a single Availability Zone. If you have Multi_AZ mode enabled in ES, you can supply a second subnet, which then must be in the other AZ that the ES cluster spans as well.

Comment: You can also configure the `availability_zone_count` to allow ES to be stretched across 3 AZs for better availability (particularly if you don't have dedicated masters) but your ES cluster must have a multiple of instances per AZ. So if you configure a 2 AZ cluster then you need 2/4/6/8... instances and a 3 AZ cluster needs 3/6/9/12... instances.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.